# /TASKER/ Voice Command on Bluetooth Connect

Tags: bluetooth, voice-command, tasker

Got a new bluetooth radio in my car and want to add voice control when it is connected.

I was thinking that when it either first connects it listens once so I can open up the music app of my choice or to have it constantly listening though I don't know how smooth that would work out.

Any ideas? I already have it setup to disable the unlock screen and open Slacker.  Want to do this cause I still have to look at my phone occassionally and want to try not to.

Comment: Does the bluetooth device have a "call" button, or is it only for audio playing? In most bluetooth hands-free setups, you can initiate voice dialing with that button. "voice dialing" in the android sense is the generic voice input which has a number of options, but you could presumably intercept this with Tasker, instead.

Comment: It has a call button that just brings up another menu to search for calls by dialed, missed, phonebook etc.